# After Brexit will the UK still be a member of the Council of Europe and be subject to the ECHR?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, council-of-europe

After Brexit will the UK still be a member of the Council of Europe?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, they did not announce their intention to leave the Council, and there are plenty of council members which are not EU members.

Comment: Addressing the tile, page 52 of the chequers plan even states " The UK is committed to membership of the European Convention
on Human Rights (ECHR). " https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/725288/The_future_relationship_between_the_United_Kingdom_and_the_European_Union.pdf

Comment: Well, they certainly made a lot of noise since then on the matter https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/why-doesnt-the-uk-want-to-be-part-of-the-echr